# logging how to control the times in which flush to log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, flush

I've to use logging module and wonder if there is a way to log into existing log file , by appending my data to the existing file and more important if I can control the times I flush into the file.

Currently I need to be able to flush all the time to the file because, there are cases in which the script running the logic with the logging can crash, so I need to know exactly where my program stopped.

Any ideas and code examples?
Thanks

Comment: Does the crash generate an Exception?

Comment: @unutbu: I'm not sure, I think not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `logging.FileHandler` and choose an existing log file, by default it will append to that file.  The method that actually writes the log record is the `emit()` method on logging handlers.  If you look at the source code for the `FileHandler`, it `flush`'s after *every* write, so it should be doing what you want by default.

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.FileHandler('/path/to/log.txt')
log.addHandler(handler)

log.warning('This is a message')
```

Comment: Do we have such handler with log rotation also?

Comment: @JavaSa `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`